# Why is this event handler throwing an exception multiple times?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a XamMaskedInput for IP address input. It looks like:
[image]

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Infragistics.Controls.Editors;
using System.Net;

namespace Customizing.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for IpRangeFields.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class IpRangeFields : UserControl
    {
        public IpRangeFields()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Start_OnLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var input = (XamMaskedInput) sender;
            try
            {
                var ip = input.Text.Replace("-", ".");
                var address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => input.Focus()));
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When the user put wrong IP address, then it will throw `System.FormatException`. The problem is, it throws the exception for many times, that my wpf application frizzed. How can I solve this problem?

After exception occurs, it should not leave the input box. How can I do this?

Comment: If you take out the line `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => input.Focus()));` does the problem go away?

Comment: Use WPF's validation instead of hand-coding your own. Preventing focus change on validation failures is standard functionality

Comment: You should also avoid `IPAddress.Parse` and use `IPAddress.TryParse` instead. No exceptions that way. You should also never ever ever catch `Exception`. In this case you should only catch `FormatException` (if you continue to use `Parse`).

Comment: I just coded up a sample app and the above code works fine - although I used a `TextBox` rather than `XamMaskedInput`. Something else must be going on here.

Answer (score 4):

You're registering to an event that happens often, and you're using `IPAddress.Parse` which will throw if it can't parse the IP address.

Instead, check the validity of the IP address by using `TryParse`:

```
var ip = input.Text.Replace("-", ".");
IPAddress ipAddress;
if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out ipAddress))
{
    // The address is invalid.
}
```

Another suggestion would be to use WPFs built in validation mechanisms to validate your IP. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more on how to do that.

Comment: This won't prevent the focus leaving the text box. The OP is simply trying to do validation in the wrong way

Comment: @Enigmativity The OP states that the problem is *"FormatException being thrown"* often. It makes sense.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've added a link to WPF validation mechanisms, perhaps that will help the OP validate the address properly.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I don't think that this makes sense that this is the issue. I suspect if he puts his "focus invoke" code in your `if` statement that he will still have the same problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity Lets let the OP answer then.